# How to disable dragging on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drag-and-drop

I want to experiment disabling dragging links in Chrome. Basically, you click on a link or image and then drag it around. I want a Javascript code to help me disable drag on every part of Chrome.

I also want this feature to work on URL and new tab too, other Javascripts I tested don't seem to work on the new tab page. Is there any JavaScript code that will help me able to disable this feature?

I can't seem to find what JavaScript code that will turn off dragging on Chrome. Can anyone help solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Listen `dragstart` on `document`, and prevent the default action, like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('dragstart', e => e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
```

Comment: It works but is there a code for the URL? Because I can still drag links in URL.

Comment: Do you mean the addressbar? That's not possible, you can disable dragging only on your own page, you can't control the browser or other pages with JS.